# LibGDX+AndroidStudio: How to print something on the logcat-console?

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, logcat, android-logcat

I´m working on a small libGDX project by using AndroidStudio. I´m a beginner :D. 
However I want to print something on the logcat-console on this way:

```
Gdx.app.log("#INFO", "My message.");
```

But excecuting this my logcat console doesn´t show anything. I don´t know how to do it the right way. No error is occurrs.

Hope you can help :D ~ Henri

Comment: Make sure any filtering is turned d'offrir on your logcat console and that you didn't search for anything in the console

Answer (score 0):

Try addind this line first 
`Gdx.app.setLogLevel(Application.LOG_DEBUG);`
Like stated here [LibGDX logging not showing up in logcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26241333/libgdx-logging-not-showing-up-in-logcat)